# Can't access Ubuntu(grub minimal bash error) after Windows repartitioning, Tried lot of Methods ..Please Help me out?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

I had created a dual boot Windows+ Ubuntu system.
On startup option to select Ubuntu or windows would show up and I could select either of them and use my lap happily..I had data of 300 gb in Ubuntu and the rest 700 gb for windows.
But recently ,while using Windows , I partitioned one of my drive which had excess space and transferred the space to my c drive ..
After I did that whenever I start my computer instead of showing the dual boot option it is showing the "minimal bash grub black screen".
So to use Windows I type exit on the grub screen and I can safely enter windows ..but I am concerned because I can't go into Ubuntu anymore and fear that my important data is Ubuntu is lost forever.

**I tried boot-repair disk .It does not show the recommended repair option.
I tried Ubuntu live CD and tried boot-repair from there still the same issue.**

[My partitions as viwed from Windows image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDbmo.png)
My partition manager in windows shows that the space i previosly reserved for ubuntu for its installation as Unallocated

Please help I have exams next week and my course materials are stored in Ubuntu..

[GPARTED IMAGE OF THE DRIVES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOHlW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably see all your partitions, including ubuntu, if you boot from an ubuntu installation stick and select 'Try ubuntu'. This live session should give you access to your data. But you can also try to fix grub from there:

Try to locate the partition of the Linux installation. A command

```
mount |grep '^\/dev\/'
```

tells you which partition devices were mounted where in the file system. In your case the EFI partition seems to be /dev/sda1, and your linux installation may be at /dev/sda4. Remember these partition names, and unmount them if they are still mounted (e.g. click in file manager the upward pointing triangle next to the disk icon).

Now give the following commands, substituting if necessary the proper partition names for /dev/sda4 and /dev/sda1:

```
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
for f in proc dev dev/pts sys run; do mount -B /$f /mnt/$f; done
chroot /mnt
```

Now you are running the *installed* ubuntu as root. Enter the
following commands:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
grub-install
update-grub
umount /boot/efi
```

Terminate this chroot session with Control-D, and then terminate the live session.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but i cant find the partition even in live cd its just shown as unallocated space when i used gparted .so i cant use "sda" thing ..i will upload the image from gparted above ..please check it

Comment: The only other suggestion that i have is trying  to recover the linux partition with testdisk. This utility does not appear to be on the live system, so you would have to install it first. There are quite a few posts on askubuntu on testdisk.